# Undefined is not an object evaluating this.state/this.props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scope, react-native, jsx

How do I bind a function outside of scope in React Native? I'm getting the errors:

```
undefined is not an object evaluating this.state
```

&

```
undefined is not an object evaluating this.props
```

I'm using the render method to evoke `renderGPSDataFromServer()` when the data has been loaded. The problem is, I'm trying to use `_buttonPress()` and `calcRow()` inside of `renderGPSDataFromServer()`, but I'm getting those errors.

I've added

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._buttonPress = this._buttonPress.bind(this);
    this.calcRow = this.calcRow.bind(this);
```

to my constructor and I've changed `_buttonPress() {` to `_buttonPress = () =>  {` and still nothing.

I think I understand the problem but I don't know how to fix it:

```
renderLoadingView() {
    return (
        <View style={[styles.cardContainer, styles.loading]}>
            <Text style={styles.restData}>
                Loading ...
            </Text>
        </View>
    )
}

_buttonPress = () =>  {
    this.props.navigator.push({
        id: 'Main'
    })
}

renderGPSDataFromServer =() => {
    const {loaded} = this.state;
    const {state} = this.state;

    return this.state.dataArr.map(function(data, i){
        return(
            <View style={[styles.cardContainer, styles.modularBorder, styles.basePadding]} key={i}>
                <View style={styles.cardContentLeft}>
                    <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button}
                        onPress={this._buttonPress().bind(this)}>
                        <Text style={styles.restData}>View Video</Text>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                </View>

          <View style={styles.cardContentRight}>
            <Text style={styles.restData}>{i}</Text>
            <View style={styles.gpsDataContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.gpsData}>
              {Number(data.lat).toFixed(2)}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.gpsData}>{Number(data.long).toFixed(2)}</Text>
            </View>
            <Text  style={styles.gpsData}>
            {this.calcRow(55,55).bind(this)}
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      );
    });
}

render = ()=> {
    if (!this.state.loaded) {
      return this.renderLoadingView();
    }
    return(
      <View>
        {this.renderGPSDataFromServer()}
      </View>
    )
}};
```

How do I go about fixing this and in this case what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because, the function inside the `map` method creates a different context. You can use arrow functions as the callback in the `map` method for lexical binding. That should solve the issue you are having.

```js
renderGPSDataFromServer =() => {

    const {loaded} = this.state;
    const {state} = this.state;

    return this.state.dataArr.map((data, i) => {
      return(
        <View style={[styles.cardContainer, styles.modularBorder, styles.basePadding]} key={i}>

          <View style={styles.cardContentLeft}>
            <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button}
             onPress={this._buttonPress().bind(this)}>
            <Text style={styles.restData}>View Video</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.cardContentRight}>
            <Text style={styles.restData}>{i}</Text>
            <View style={styles.gpsDataContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.gpsData}>
              {Number(data.lat).toFixed(2)}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.gpsData}>{Number(data.long).toFixed(2)}</Text>
            </View>
            <Text  style={styles.gpsData}>
            {this.calcRow(55,55).bind(this)}
            </Text>
          </View>

        </View>
      );
    });
  }
```

> Also, once you've used arrow functions in the class function definition you
>   don't need to bind them in constructor like:

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this._customMethodDefinedUsingFatArrow = this._customMethodDefinedUsingFatArrow.bind(this)
}
```

> Also, once you have defined class functions as arrow functions, you
>   don't need to use the arrow functions while calling them either:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  myfunc = () => {
    this.nextFunc()
  }

  nextFunc = () => {
    console.log('hello hello')
  }

  render() {
    // this will give you the desired result
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.myFunc} />
    )
    
    // you don't need to do this
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.myFunc()} />
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> ## this.props are read-only

[*React docs - component and props*](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html)

And therefore a component shouldn't try a to modify them let alone mutate them as you are doing here:

```
  _buttonPress = () =>  {
      this.props.navigator.push({
        id: 'Main'
      })
  }
```

I'd suggest using state instead:

```
_buttonPress = () =>  {
  this.setState = {
    ...this.state,
    navigator: {
      ...this.state.navigator,
      id: 'Main'
    }
  }
}
```

---

Regarding your binding issue:

the `.map` method takes a 2nd argument that is used to set the value of `this` when the callback is invoked.

In the context of your question, you just need to pass `this`as the 2nd argument to you `.map` method to bind the components scope's `this` to it.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is the problem, but I think is code is wrong, and may be potentially causing your issue.

```
<View style={styles.cardContentLeft}>
  <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button}
   onPress={this._buttonPress().bind(this)}>
  <Text style={styles.restData}>View Video</Text>
  </TouchableHighlight>
</View>
```

specifically this line `onPress={this._buttonPress().bind(this)}>`
you are invoking the function and binding it at the same time.

The correct way to do this would be so

```
onPress={this._buttonPress.bind(this)}>
```

this way the function will be called only onPress.

Answer (score 0):

You are going in the right direction, but there is still a minor issue. You are passing a `function` to your `map` callback that has a different scope (`this`) than your component (because it is not an arrow function), so when you do `bind(this)`, you are rebinding your callback to use the scope from `map`. I think this should work, it basically turns the callback that you pass to `map` into an arrow function. Also, since you `bind` your function in the constructor, you do not need to do it again:

```
  // The constructor logic remains the same
  // ....
  renderLoadingView() {
      return (
      <View style={[styles.cardContainer, styles.loading]}>
        <Text style={styles.restData}>
          Loading ...
        </Text>
      </View>
      )
    }

  _buttonPress = () =>  {
      this.props.navigator.push({
        id: 'Main'
      })
  }

  renderGPSDataFromServer =() => {

    const {loaded} = this.state;
    const {state} = this.state;

    return this.state.dataArr.map((data, i) => {
      return(
        <View style={[styles.cardContainer, styles.modularBorder, styles.basePadding]} key={i}>

          <View style={styles.cardContentLeft}>
            <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button}
             onPress={this._buttonPress}>
            <Text style={styles.restData}>View Video</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.cardContentRight}>
            <Text style={styles.restData}>{i}</Text>
            <View style={styles.gpsDataContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.gpsData}>
              {Number(data.lat).toFixed(2)}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.gpsData}>{Number(data.long).toFixed(2)}</Text>
            </View>
            <Text  style={styles.gpsData}>
            {this.calcRow(55,55).bind(this)}
            </Text>
          </View>

        </View>
      );
    });
  }

  render = ()=> {
    if (!this.state.loaded) {
      return this.renderLoadingView();
    }
    return(
      <View>
        {this.renderGPSDataFromServer()}
      </View>
    )
  }};
```

Comment: I also think you should follow Pineda's advice on how to deal with props I totally overlooked that on my answer.