# this object in React Component using ES6 classes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this

I have a `MsgInput` component with a `textarea` which `onKeyUp` triggers a handler function. Inside the handler function, I try reading the props using `this.props`, but not sure why props is undefined here. Ofcourse the workaroud is to use `this.handler.bind(this)`.

```
export class MsgInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
  }

  inputHandler(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
      this.props.onNewMessage({content: e.target.value});
      e.target.value = '';
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div className="controls">
            <textarea onKeyDown={this.inputHandler.bind(this)} className="msg-input" placeholder="Write something" disabled={!this.props.auth}></textarea>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined is not an object evaluating this.state/this.props](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774399/undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-this-state-this-props)

Comment: If you are using a transform anyways, check out the `@autobind` decorator: https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-decorators#autobind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React with ES6 classes doesn't auto bind your callbacks to the component instance, so you have to do it yourself as you already did. Otherwise `this` would not available in the callback.

---

```
this.inputHandler.bind(this)
```

This is not a work around, but the way it is supposed to be.

Another alternative is to utilise ES6 arrow functions which would automatically bind `this`.

```
<textarea onKeyDown={(e) => this.inputHandler(e)}></textarea>
```

---

**Caveat:** Using `.bind` or arrow function inside your jsx will create a new function on every render which is a performance impediment.

As a last resort you can bind methods in your constructor which wouldn't have the performance penalty of arrow functions.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.inputHandler = this.inputHandler.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: plus one for arrow functions. the calling of bind seemed tedious to me

Comment: nice, thanks;-)  you can accept the answer if it clears things up.

Comment: Why create a new function on every render? I'd rather `.bind` inside the `constructor`.

Comment: yeah, that's another point. Functional callback is created every time on redner.