# Why does React make props and state properties of the component rather than parameters to render?

Tags: reactjs

React is designed around immutability, so it seems a little odd to me that it depends to fundamentally on two mutable properties of the Component. If they'd implemented it as `render(props, state)`, it would reduce temptation to modify state in other functions, and fit more cleanly into the notion that `render` is a purely functional operation.

I feel like if I understood the design decision I'd be able to use React more effectively.

Comment: *it would reduce temptation to modify state in other functions*
why?

Comment: I think the idea is that you have one or more high level components to maintain state and then by convention use stateless components as you move down the tree. So is your thought that application state should be maintained at some higher level and only passed through components ie all components are stateless?

Comment: Also, props are immutable, and in your example, what would be the difference between state and props? Why would you need both?

Comment: Both props and state are immutable over the course of a single render call. Props are passed down and state belongs to the object, but it's not something you're supposed to set directly.

Answer (score 1):

`props` and `state` are to be treated as immutable. [props are read-only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40774888/2902660) and any updates to component state should be done using `setState` to avoid your changes being overwritten.

The `render` method doesn't have to have the notion of being a pure function where a persistent/changing state needs to be handled.

Abstracting your components into *stateful* and *stateless* (functional) components is something you can look into if you are looking to make your React components presentational/dumb/pure.

You could build your application building purely functional components but either:

- you'd have to find a way to manage state changes to pass onto your functional components
- your application is so simple as to have no state or no state that changes with complex logic.

Comment: I know, but that's not really answering the question. Why are they implemented as properties of the component rather than as arguments to render.

Comment: You may not want to render on every change of certain props/state. Plus you may not want to update the state from within the render method. Consider an async call to update the state. Would you put that in the render method?